# Missing "On My Computer" option?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook-2011

I have several users running Outlook 2011 for Mac.  1 user does not have "On My Computer" listed in the left pane.  I checked Preferences -> General to make sure the box to hide this is unchecked.  All my other users have this listed.

Recommendations on what to look at?